# Saving AJAX stream to a PDF file

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to save the result of a XMLHTTPRequest to a PDF file.

I am communicating with a server I am calling to get a chunk of data formatted as PDF data.
I'm using XMLHTTPRequets to log into the server, then make a search request which in return creates a PDF which is streamed back to me though the XMLHTTPRequest.

I need to save that result as a PDF so I can later open it in Acrobat.

When I save the response text to a file the result is not a valid PDF. The request is doing something to the stream which makes it invalid as a PDF.

I have no control over that server so I cant make it send back a link to a temporary valid PDF file.

Is there a way around that ?
Is there a way to encode that stream into a valid PDF file ?

I am using Javascript for that application.

Thanks

Erez

Comment: unless i'm missing something, this violates the same-origin policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is return from your http server an xml file like the following:

```
<resp><![CDATA[YOURPDFSTREAM]]></resp>
```

and them retrieve the RESP node to build your pdf file.

Don't forget to encode your stream in the desired encoding format as well.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what a RESP is ;-).  Do u mean that I'll need to gram the responce XML and recreate the PDF from scratch ?

Comment: ooooh the engine of stackoverflow erases tags unless they are under the "code" tags, that's why you couldn't see it... sorry